# Removing duplicate sub-dataframes from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, for example

```
df_dupl = pd.DataFrame({
    'EVENT_TIME': ['00:01', '00:01', '00:01', '00:03', '00:03', '00:03', '00:06', '00:06', '00:06', '00:08', '00:08', '00:10', '00:10', '00:11', '00:11', '00:13', '00:13', '00:13'],
    'UNIQUE_ID': [123, 123, 123, 125, 125, 125, 123, 123, 123, 127, 127, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123],
    'Value1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    'Value2': [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 1.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 1.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2]
})
```

I want to remove the sequences of rows that have the same values as the previous (by EVENT_TIME) rows with the same UNIQUE_ID.
For the example the result should look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'EVENT_TIME': ['00:01', '00:01', '00:01', '00:03', '00:03', '00:03', '00:08', '00:08', '00:10', '00:10', '00:11', '00:11', '00:13', '00:13', '00:13'],
    'UNIQUE_ID': [123, 123, 123, 125, 125, 125, 127, 127, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123],
    'Value1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A'],
    'Value2': [0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 1.3, 0.2, 0.1, 1.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2]
}).
```

The rows with time 00:06 should be removed, because the previous sub-dataframe with UNIQUE_ID 123 (time 00:01) is identical.
On the other hand the rows with time 00:13 should remain - they are also identical to the rows with Time 00:01, but there are other rows with UNIQUE_ID 123 in between.
The key thinq is that I want to compare the whole sub-dataframes, not single rows.

I can achieve the desired result by using the folllowing function, but it is quite slow.

```
def del_dupl_gr(df):
    out = []
    for x in df['UNIQUE_ID'].unique():
        prev_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for y in df[df['UNIQUE_ID'] == x]['EVENT_TIME'].unique():
            test_df = df[(df['UNIQUE_ID'] == x) & (df['EVENT_TIME'] == y)]
            if not test_df.iloc[:, 2:].reset_index(drop=True).equals(prev_df.iloc[:, 2:].reset_index(drop=True)):
                out.append(test_df)
                prev_df = test_df
    return pd.concat(out).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The real dataframe is quite large (over million rows) and this looping takes a lot of time. I am sure there must be proper (or at least faster) way to do this.

**Results**

Thanks for all the submitted answers. I compared their speed. In some cases i slightly edited the methods to produce exactly the same results. So in all sort_values methods I added kind='stable' to ensure that the order is preserved, and at the end I added .reset_index(drop=True).

| Method | 1000 rows | 10 000 rows | 100 000 rows |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| original | 556 ms | 5.41 s | Not tested |
| mozway | 1.24 s | 10.1 s | Not tested |
| Andrej Kesely | 696 ms | 4.56 s | Not tested |
| Quang Hoang | 11.3 ms | 34.1 ms | 318 ms |

**EDIT**

The accepted answer works fine if there are no NaN values in the dataframe. In my case (though not mentioned in the original question), there are NaN values which I need to be treated as equal. So the comparison part of the code needs to be modified as follows (the other parts remain the same)

```
dup = ((df_dupl.groupby(['UNIQUE_ID',enums])[value_cols].shift().eq(df_dupl[value_cols]) | (df_dupl.groupby(['UNIQUE_ID',enums])[value_cols].shift().isna() & df_dupl[value_cols].isna())).all(axis=1).groupby(groups).transform('all') & sizes.groupby([df_dupl['UNIQUE_ID'],enums]).diff().eq(0))
```

This makes the method about 50% slower, but it remains by far the fastest of all the solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is to shift the rows by enumeration, then compare:

```
# the value columns
value_cols = df.columns[2:]

# groups are identified as `EVENT_TIME` and `UNIQUE_ID`
groupby = df_dupl.groupby(['EVENT_TIME','UNIQUE_ID'])['Value1']

# these are the groups
groups = groupby.ngroup()

# enumeration within the groups
enums = groupby.cumcount()

# sizes of the groups - populated across the rows
sizes = groupby.transform('size')

dup = (df_dupl.groupby(['UNIQUE_ID',enums])[value_cols].shift(). # shift by enumeration within `UNIQUE_ID`
     .eq(df_dupl[value_cols]).all(axis=1)                        # equal the current rows
     .groupby(groups).transform('all')                           # identical across the groups
 &
 sizes.groupby([df_dupl['UNIQUE_ID'],enums]).diff().eq(0).       # and the group size are equal too
)

# output
df_dupl.loc[~dup]
```

Output:

```
   EVENT_TIME  UNIQUE_ID Value1  Value2
0       00:01        123      A     0.3
1       00:01        123      B     0.2
2       00:01        123      A     0.2
3       00:03        125      A     0.1
4       00:03        125      B     1.3
5       00:03        125      A     0.2
9       00:08        127      A     0.1
10      00:08        127      B     1.3
11      00:10        123      A     0.3
12      00:10        123      B     0.2
13      00:11        123      C     0.3
14      00:11        123      B     0.2
15      00:13        123      A     0.3
16      00:13        123      B     0.2
17      00:13        123      A     0.2
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer, as it is by far the fastest of all the presented solutions. Just a small note, the first line of code should be value_cols = df_dupl.columns[2:]. It took me some time to discover why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could form groups and hash the subdataframes, then [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) to compare to the previous block:

```
def hash_df(g):
    return hash(tuple(pd.util.hash_pandas_object(g, index=False)))

groups = ['UNIQUE_ID', 'EVENT_TIME']
tmp = (df_dupl.sort_values(by=list(df_dupl))
       .set_index(groups)
       .groupby(groups, sort=False).agg(hash_df)
      )

keep = tmp.ne(tmp.groupby('UNIQUE_ID').shift()).any(axis=1)

out = df_dupl[df_dupl.merge(keep.reset_index(name='flag'))['flag']]
```

Output:

```
   EVENT_TIME  UNIQUE_ID Value1  Value2
0       00:01        123      A     0.3
1       00:01        123      B     0.2
2       00:01        123      A     0.2
3       00:03        125      A     0.1
4       00:03        125      B     1.3
5       00:03        125      A     0.2
9       00:08        127      A     0.1
10      00:08        127      B     1.3
11      00:10        123      A     0.3
12      00:10        123      B     0.2
13      00:11        123      C     0.3
14      00:11        123      B     0.2
15      00:13        123      A     0.3
16      00:13        123      B     0.2
17      00:13        123      A     0.2
```

Intermediates:

```
#tmp
                                   Value1               Value2
UNIQUE_ID EVENT_TIME                                          
123       00:01      -2647391080000972640 -2479202283702687367
125       00:03      -2647391080000972640  1479523423813153529
123       00:06      -2647391080000972640 -2479202283702687367
127       00:08      -1564261656412067059 -4515207542275771698
123       00:10      -1564261656412067059 -2126568776299078705
          00:11       2187186574447344670 -5299110227501839425
          00:13      -2647391080000972640 -2479202283702687367
# flag
   EVENT_TIME  UNIQUE_ID Value1  Value2   flag
0       00:01        123      A     0.3   True
1       00:01        123      B     0.2   True
2       00:01        123      A     0.2   True
3       00:03        125      A     0.1   True
4       00:03        125      B     1.3   True
5       00:03        125      A     0.2   True
6       00:06        123      A     0.3  False
7       00:06        123      B     0.2  False
8       00:06        123      A     0.2  False
9       00:08        127      A     0.1   True
10      00:08        127      B     1.3   True
11      00:10        123      A     0.3   True
12      00:10        123      B     0.2   True
13      00:11        123      C     0.3   True
14      00:11        123      B     0.2   True
15      00:13        123      A     0.3   True
16      00:13        123      B     0.2   True
17      00:13        123      A     0.2   True
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but this seems to be actually slower than my original function. On a dataframe with 5000 rows I get 3.39 s ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) for your approach and 1.79 s ± 248 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) for my function.

Comment: `hash` is expensive, and `.agg` is not much parallel if there are a lot of groups.

Comment: @user23503493 I guess this depend on how many groups you have and the size of the subdataframes

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```py
def fn(g):
    groups = g.groupby("EVENT_TIME").agg(tuple)
    mask = (groups == groups.shift()).all(axis=1)
    return g[g["EVENT_TIME"].isin(groups.index[~mask])]


out = (
    df_dupl.groupby("UNIQUE_ID")
    .apply(fn, include_groups=False)
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values(by="EVENT_TIME")
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    UNIQUE_ID EVENT_TIME Value1  Value2
0         123      00:01      A     0.3
1         123      00:01      B     0.2
2         123      00:01      A     0.2
10        125      00:03      A     0.1
11        125      00:03      B     1.3
12        125      00:03      A     0.2
13        127      00:08      A     0.1
14        127      00:08      B     1.3
3         123      00:10      A     0.3
4         123      00:10      B     0.2
5         123      00:11      C     0.3
6         123      00:11      B     0.2
7         123      00:13      A     0.3
8         123      00:13      B     0.2
9         123      00:13      A     0.2
```